# how can i set icon for actionbar menu items

Tags: android, android-layout

i simply want to use and set icon for `actionBar` menu items in `xml` and this is my code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />


    <item android:id="@+id/my_action"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
          android:hint="@string/your_mind"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/my_action" />

    <item android:id="@+id/about_me"
          android:title="@string/about"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" //CUSTOM ICON
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" //DEFAULT ANDROID ICONS
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

The default or custom icon do not show with menu items.

**SCREEN SHOT:**
this is screen shot is latest running project with set icons for menu items. but menu items dont have any icons.

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml

Comment: @Prag's Google filtering any country and we have could not access for documents. :(

Comment: ic_home is present on your drawable folder? can you please provide the output?

Comment: @SaifuddinSarker yes. i cab use this icon for any where, but that could not set for menu items

Comment: try this android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_home" for default

Comment: try `withText` attribute... android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"..this may help you..

Comment: @SaifuddinSarker  your helps dont resolve my problem. :(

Comment: @Prag's don't resolve.

Comment: Can u post the full code? With this code..I can't find where the issue exists!

Comment: can you see other menus in layout?

Comment: @Prag's all of menu items show in ActionBar but i can not set any icons for those

Comment: @TuxWorld please provide screenshot and whole layout where you are using menu. I dont found any wrong with the code you provide, so there is one possiblity is not showing cause of overflow in you layout. sorry for late reply

Comment: I think you problem is in "android:ShowAsAction", please i would like to reffer this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917973/showasaction-ifroom-doesnt-show-the-item-even-when-there-is-plenty-of-room . put this http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto hope it will solve

Answer (score 0):

The icon can be shown only inside the ActionBar but inside the overflow menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

Comment: don't resolve problem. i want to have icon's menu with `ifroom`