# ActionBar buttons always forced to overflow if iRoom attribute is set

Tags: android, android-actionbar

With `iRoom` attribute Android should  view the buttons if there is enough space and overflow them otherwise. 
Unfortunately `ActionBar` buttons despite the available space and the screen size are always forced to overflow if `iRoom` attribute is set and are shown only if I use the attribute `always`.

[image]

My ActionBar menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_social_share"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:icon="@drawable/action_social_share"
            android:title="@string/action_social_share"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:icon="@drawable/action_home"
            android:title="@string/action_home"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/action_about"/>

</menu>
```

My Activity

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class InfoViewerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ActionBar bar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_infoviewer);

        bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.info_viewer, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                //TO DO
                return true;
            case R.id.action_social_share:
                //TO DO
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //TO DO
                return true;
            case R.id.action_about:
                //TO DO
                return true;
            default:
                // Handle your other action bar items...
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

I cannot find the cause of this issue and have used similar code various times without this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the first answer on this topic [showAsAction="ifRoom" doesn't show the item even when there is plenty of room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917973/showasaction-ifroom-doesnt-show-the-item-even-when-there-is-plenty-of-room)
Might be a namespace problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't answer to my question, as have said the size and the space available is ignored and no button are shown if use iRoom this is not normal behaviour, at least I should see 2 buttons

Comment: in the first answer there is written that the number of items should be 4 by default... I have only ONE button in addition to the menu button, see the screnshot that have added... this should not be the normal behaviour... I know that using `always` I can force to show the button but I want to fix the issue with iRoom

Comment: I am refering to the answer which begins with "I hope I am not too late in coming to the party...."

Answer (score 0):

android:orderInCategory is denoted by an Integer. 
It indicates the order of "importance" of the item, within a group.
Either remove that attribute or set it to a value like 1

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_social_share"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_social_share"
        android:title="@string/action_social_share"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_home"
        android:title="@string/action_home"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_about"/>
```

Comment: I know this, but my problem is that should show at least 2 buttons of menu not only one.